# Unable to connect to MySQL via IP Address

Tags: mysql

I tried to use google, but it seems that there is no solution, at least not to my case.

i'm a C# programmer, and recenly I decided to try out to build some application which use data.
For that, I started to using MySQL.

Currently, I have installed:

```
  - MySQL Community Server 5.5.20
  - MySQL Workbench 5.2.37
```

In the workbench I have **Server Instance** that has hostname = **localhost**.
I have a **connection** too, which poining to the hostname = **localhost**.
It works perfect.
I finished the development of my application, and it works perfect with the database.

## As for the problem:

Now, I want my application to work from other machines.
For that, I changed the following:

```
  1) From the workbench: I removed the Server Instance containing localhost.
  2) I created new Server Instance, but now I chose "Remote Host" and I
     put my IP Adress: 79.179.XX.XXX (X - to hide my ip there)
     and then I pressed next.
```

Now, while it trying to test the connection it says:
***Can't connect to MySQL server on '79.179.XX.XXX' (10061)***

My application also can't open the connection when I change the hostname
in the connection string to my ip.
Note: I has router, and I forwarded 3306 port and the port is opened.
If you need any information I will edit and write.

**What can be the problem there?

How can I fix it?**
*Thank you.*

Comment: Have you tried disabling the firewalls, to be sure it's not a firewall problem?

Comment: Yes. I already tried that, and it not still not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the my.cnf file to make sure skip-networking is not enabled.

Comment: Hi. I only have my.ini, and there is no value "skip-networking". But in the my-template.ini here is something like that:     [mysqld]

<<ifdef SKIPNETWORKING>>  
skip-networking  
enable-named-pipe

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your user name is `blammy`, did you setup a `blammy@79.179.xxx.xxx` in mysql?  If no, then you need to do so.

Try using the mysql client to connect to 79.179.xxx.xxx, if the account is the cause, then login should fail here as well.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I didn't setup any username. to setup one, I must setup first a Server Instance. as I said, I can't make the server instance with the hostname 79.179.XX.XXX. Should I leave the hostname of the server instance localhost and then create username with my IP?